# How to get file names under a given directory in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have some audio files saved under the Documents directory. I just want to get those file names so that I can display them in a tableview. Right now I'm using

```
NSArray* files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                      contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:DOCUMENTS_FOLDER error:&err];
```

How can I extract just the file names into an array using that returned NSArray* files Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `-stringByDeletingPathExtension` on each of the filenames.

Comment: Thanks. but how can I view the string value of the file names? I tried NSLog(@"%@", files[0]); but it returns "NSCFArray". Which property should I look to? something like files[0].filename?

Comment: Try using <code>[files objectAtIndex:0]</code>, to get element 0 of <code>files</code>, since it's an <code>NSArray</code> not a C-style array.